# How to define a dynamic route in NextJs 14 API?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js14

I want to create a blog using Next.js 14. I define this function in `api/posts/[postSlug]/route.js`. How can I get `postSlug` params in this function?

My function code:

```
// api/posts/[postSlug]/route.js
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";


export async function GET (request) {

    // const { postSlug } = params;
    const postSlug = 'test'
    console.log(request);

    const post = await prisma.post.findUnique({
        where: {
            slug: postSlug
        }
    })

    if (post)
        return NextResponse.json({
            post,
        })

    return NextResponse.json({
        status: 'error',
        message: 'not found!'
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the dynamic route parameters of any route handler by accessing the `params` object within the second function argument. Here is an example:

```js
// app/items/[slug]/route.ts

export async function GET(
  request: Request,
  { params }: { params: { slug: string } }
) {
  const { slug } = params;
  // ...
}
```

You can find more about route handlers and all of their abilities inside the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers).